# Is it possible to use the contents of a cell in a custom conditional formatting rule in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

For example, given the sheet below:

[image: A colourful sheet]

**I'd like the background colours of columns `B-D` to change automatically when I update the values in column `A`**

Is that possible? I'm looking for a solution that will work with any colour, without preprogramming the sheet in some way to be aware of a fixed set of colours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheets conditional formatting based on another cell's content](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-content)

Comment: I would say that it's a more specific case of the proposed duplicate question. I specifically want to use the other cell as a source for deciding the colour of another cell.

Comment: I don't see the difference. The referred Q&A include answers to apply conditional formatting by using a script and by using the built-in feature. Regarding the last, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53559/88163

Comment: If you want to color of the conditional formatting to be pulled from the source cell, you're going to be in scripting land.

Comment: If you make that an answer (rather than a comment) I'll select it as the best answer.

Comment: With your update I'd agree that this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer this one as the answer from the post: "[Google Spreadsheets conditional formatting based on another cell's content](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-content)" is outdated.

To answer your question: Highlight the Range that you need conditional formatting, then go to "Format > Conditional Formatting" and for each Color you will add a unique conditional format.

- Apply to Range: *the range you selected previously*
- Format Cells if: "custom formula"

  - Formula in plain English: Anything in the corresponding cell in column A on the same Row that contains the characters "Red", the formula would be:

    ```
    =A:A="Red"
    ```
  - And then just choose red background from the color picker in the conditional formatting sidebar.
  - Repeat this process for each color.

Example file here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sJtSrvFpKxmxUgzvrtIQzhYmxqeoR0FWVHpzNV5bIgQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How, in your example scenario, would I go about getting the background of a row to be, say, blue?

Comment: Highlight Row, the right click > Conditional Formatting and would setup something like this: http://prntscr.com/a52j1w

Comment: Thanks @David Knapp. Is it possible to extend this method to colour an entire row rather than just one cell?

Comment: yes just highlight the entire row and then apply the conditional formatting rules to that row.