# How can I set conditional formatting on particular cells that depend on another cell's value in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to colour the background of a row in Google Spreadsheets:

For example:

- If cell Dx = title 'To do' or 'title 'Done' then cells Fx to Nx are filled colour black.
- If cell Dx = title 'closed' the font colour of cell Ax to Nx turns green.

I can do this in Excel quite easily...

Comment: As far as I know, such functionality has not been implemented in Google Spreadsheets. The only conditional formatting you can do is on the same cell with the value.

Comment: See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-content

Answer (score 1):

Where x = 1, in New Google Sheets in Custom formula is please try:

```
=or($D1="To do",$D1="Done")
```

check Background:, choose black and for Range: enter F1:N1

add another rule with Custom formula is

```
 =$D1="closed"
```

check Background:, choose green and for range: enter A1:N1.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this web app - [Color Code+](https://script.google.com/a/macros/bryanp.com/s/AKfycbzczehiEMI26V7fXIKuvBNiVsNGnLgUk6pm7NkmJhQCii3PexVw/exec) to cover most of the basic cases.

Comment: The example in your app, isn't editable. This way people can't see the result of your code: http://goo.gl/CFg61

Comment: You have to make your own copy of it and then you can access the code.