# Color entire row based on the status in Column L

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I make my spreadsheet look like in the picture below? Starting row 5, I want to color the entire row based on the status in Column L.

[image]

Comment: Any answers on this please?

Comment: Take a look at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-content
The accepted answer there is probably exactly what you need. Or at least a good starting point.
(Since I can't comment or mark the question as duplicate because of my reputation, I had to write a new answer.)

Comment: It worked with few changes on the codes. Thanks guys! You guys are awesome.